# Why Relational Database not support by Hadoop?

Tags: database, hadoop, bigdata

Nosql Database support by Hadoop System.

May I know why Hadoop System not support Relational Database .

How to manage large relational database ?

Answer (score 3):

The following are the difference between Hadoop and RDBMS:

- Hadoop does not have support for Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation,
  and Durability.
- Low latency retrieval of data is not possible in hadoop unlike in
  RDBMS. There is no guarantee of how much time hadoop will take to
  complete a job.
- Basically, hadoop has faster write and RDBMS has faster read. Faster
  read is because of the usage of B-tree data structure for storage.
- Hadoop doesn't have a schema. RDBMS has a schema.

You can query a large structured data stored in HDFS using hive, pig, HBase, etc., but the retrieval won't be as fast as in RDBMS. My opinion would be not to use hadoop for relational operations.

Answer (score 1):

RDBMS can store data up to some Terabytes and renewing licenses is always a pain.

Eg: SQL, MySQL

Here comes MPPs(Massive Parallel Processing).. MPP Systems can handle huge data than a single node of RDBMS database since it stores data in a cluster. But there is a limit.

Eg: Netezza, Teradata.. etc

Above mentioned RDBMS & MPPs can handle structured data up to some TBs and give fast response.. can be used for OLTP.

Finally our Hadoop.. which is mainly designed to handle huge volumes(Petabytes) of data, while storing and processing on commodity hardware.. which is scalable.. Hadoop is not meant for OLTP.